# Unable to export to Monitoring service because: GaxError RPC failed, caused by 7

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a Go application that runs in the container in the VM instance and enabled Stackdriver Logging. And Stackdriver was spams a lot of log messages:

```
Unable to export to Monitoring service because: GaxError RPC failed, caused by 7:Permission monitoring.timeSeries.create denied (or the resource may not exist).. debug_error_string:{"created":"@1647697254.555306768","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:...","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Permission monitoring.timeSeries.create denied (or the resource may not exist).","grpc_status":7}
```

Here is `docker ps` of the VM instance:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS     NAMES
app_con_id     us.gcr.io/my_app                                            "/app/…"                 3 days ago   Up 3 days             ....-dev-v1-vkyr
log_agent_id   gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:1.8.9   "/entrypoint.sh /usr…"   3 days ago   Up 3 days             stackdriver-logging-agent
```

And I couldn't find any possibility to grant permission for it.

How can these messages be solved?

Comment: Please include a minimally reproducible example of your code where you're attempting to create a time series? The error is somewhat clear. Either your container is running with insufficient permissions to create the time series (search [this](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/access-control) page for `monitoring.timeSeries.create`. One possible IAM role is `roles/monitoring.editor`. (And) Or the resource type that you're using is incorrect.[Here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources)'s the list of monitored resource that is available.

Comment: @DazWilkin just by adding the **roles/monitoring.editor** it worked out for me.
Thanks